# I'm trying to create spaces in between underscores, which represent a secret phrase

Tags: c++

Naturally I'm a beginner. I'm trying to create a simple phrase guess game. So I have randomly generated a phrase. I want to set up a variable equal to the length of the random phrase, which will change every game. As the game progresses and correct guesses are made I want to fill in the under scores with correct guesses.

t _ e (space here) p _ r a _ e

this sort of thing. Right now I'm just trying to generate the reveal phrase with spaces and underscores. Thanks in advance.

```
    string phrase = verbs[random_word1] + ' ' + nouns[random_word2] + ' ' + conjunct[random_conjunct] + ' ' + result + ' ' +  adjectives[random_word3];

string revealPhrase = "";

for (i=0; i < phrase.length(); i++){
    if (phrase.at[i] == ' ')
        revealPhrase = ' ';
    else    
        revealPhrase = revealPhrase + "_ ";}

cout << revealPhrase << endl;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate you question what exactly you are not getting in this code.

Comment: If you want to fill it in with spaces anyway, why are you substituting dashes in the first place?

Comment: I posted my latest code above. I want it to be like a wheel of fortune type game.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
for (int i=0; i < phrase.length(); i++){
    if (phrase[i] == '-')
        revealPhrase += "  "; // assuming you want spaces here
    else    
        revealPhrase += "_ ";
}
```

Comment: so this gave me one line

Comment: ooga above was close. that actually gave me a line for each word which isn't bad. Ideally I want a blank for each letter in each word in the phrase.

Comment: Are you sure you copied it properly? It should give an underscore followed by a space for every letter, and two spaces for every dash.

Comment: My visual studio is crapping out. Sorry. I did notice I had ' ' in a place where you had " ". That's probably it.

Comment: I don't know. It printed 25 lines of blanks

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
char c;
string actualPhrase = "the phrase";
string revealPhrase = "__________";
int length = actualPhrase.length();
int curIndex;
while(actualPhrase.compare(revealPhrase) != 0)
{
   cin >> c;
   for(int i=0; i < length; i += 1)
   {
      if(actualPhrase[i] == c)
      {
         revealPhrase[i] = c;
      }
   }
}
```